# MySQL JSON_SET() to work with empty arrays

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `settings` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `settings`) VALUES 
    ('1', '{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 1}}'),
    ('2', '{\"foobar\": 2}'),
    ('3', '[]');
```

I want to add a new setting to a row, so I tried [JSON_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set):

```
SELECT *, JSON_SET(settings, '$.newFoo', 10) FROM test;
```

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't work on the item 3. The expected result is of course the same as on line 4; `[]` is the result of json-encoding an empty array in php, if that item doesn't have any setting.

Can make a single query that works for all the cases?

---

P.S.: What I need to do is an UPDATE, i.e. `UPDATE test SET settings=JSON_SET(...) WHERE id=?;`

Comment: Have you tried using the empty array notation for json? `('3', '{}');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by always storing the values as objects instead of arrays, in PHP you need to add a flag to the `json_encode` function:

```
json_encode($value, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

Or, as an alternative, make the field nullable and use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT *, JSON_SET(COALESCE(settings, '{}'), '$.newFoo', 10) FROM test;
```

Answer (score 7):

This stumped me as well for quite awhile but try using JSON_ARRAY() instead of the double bracket notation '[]'. For example:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `settings`) VALUES 
    ('1', '{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 1}}'),
    ('2', '{\"foobar\": 2}'),
    ('3', JSON_ARRAY());
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your call to `JSON_SET` is not behaving as you expect is that the syntax you need to work with JSON arrays differs from what you need to work with individual JSON.  Consider the following query, which adds a JSON to an empty array:

```
SELECT JSON_SET('[]', '$[0]', '{"newFoo": 10}') AS output;
```

This prints:

```
["{\"newFoo\": 10}"]
```

### Demo

So the `JSON_SET` function appears to have two behaviors to it.  When operating on JSON proper, it can either insert new keys or update keys which already exist.  When operating on arrays, it can insert/update elements of the array, which might be entire JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE .. WHEN` conditional operator to handle this in single query. Also, since your datatype for `settings` is `Json`, you will need to `Cast()` it to string (Char) first for checking `[]`:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN CAST(settings AS CHAR) = '[]'  
            THEN JSON_SET('{}', '$.newFoo', 10)
            ELSE JSON_SET(settings, '$.newFoo', 10) 
       END AS modified_settings 
FROM test;
```

---

`Update` query for the same would be as follows:

```
UPDATE test 
SET settings = CASE WHEN CAST(settings AS CHAR) = '[]'  
                    THEN JSON_SET('{}', '$.newFoo', 10)
                    ELSE JSON_SET(settings, '$.newFoo', 10) 
               END
```

Comment: Actually I want to make an UPDATE not a select, the select was just to show the result